# python Genfromtxt how convert negative integer in to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, genfromtxt

```
img = np.genfromtxt (path+file,dtype=int,
                invalid_raise=False,
                missing_values= (all negatives), <<<---------------
                usemask=False,
                filling_values=0)
```

I need catch negative integers and replace them with 0.
maybe someone can write some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `.clip()` as follows:

```
img = img.clip(0)
```

Comment: TypeError: clip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a_max'

Comment: @Klasik, Please see changes